# Wait for Google places Photo request inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, google-places-api

I am trying to understand how to use Asynctasks with other requests in them, So im getting a photo using Google places while inside an AsyncTask.

What i am getting is that while the request is processing, the Asynctask finishes before i get the photo so its a null.

I believe the problem to be that while the request is being made, the task is being finished and continues to the rest of the code.

My AsyncTask class is built like so:

```
private class AsyncPhotoBuilder extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Bitmap[][]>{

    ProgressBar pb;
    int status = 0;

    private void setProgressBar(ProgressBar progressBar){
        this.pb = progressBar;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap[][] bitmaps) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmaps);
        Log.d("debug", "onpost");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        pb.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap[][] doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        try{
            int xSize = 4, ySize = 4;
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PHOTO_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
            String meta = prefs.getString("meta", "empty");
            if(!meta.equals("empty")){
                int loc = meta.indexOf(photoref_loc);
                String holder = meta.substring(loc+photoref_loc.length());
                PhotoMetadata temp = PhotoMetadata.builder(holder.substring(0, holder.length()-1)).build();


                FetchPhotoRequest photoRequest = FetchPhotoRequest.builder(temp)
                        .setMaxWidth(800) // Optional.
                        .setMaxHeight(800) // Optional.
                        .build();
                //Starts a request for a photo
                placesClient.fetchPhoto(photoRequest).addOnSuccessListener((fetchPhotoResponse) -> {
                    Photo_Bitmap.set(fetchPhotoResponse.getBitmap());
                    int width, height;

                    width = Photo_Bitmap.get().getWidth()/xSize;
                    height = Photo_Bitmap.get().getHeight()/ySize;
                    //Cuts photo into a 4x4
                    for(int i = 0; i < xSize; i++){
                        for(int j = 0; j < ySize; j++){
                            PuzzleList[i][j] = Bitmap.createBitmap(Photo_Bitmap.get(), i*width, j*height, width, height);
                            status++;
                            publishProgress(status);
                            
                        }
                    }
                    //Once finished cutting photo raise flag.
                    ready_flag = true;
                    Log.d("debug", "finish");
                }).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
                    if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                        ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                        int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                        // Handle error with given status code.
                        Log.e("debug", "Photo not found: " + exception.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception", "Error in splitting photo: " + e);
        }
        return PuzzleList;
    }
}
```

From what i can understand onPostExecute happens before the request is done.
I tried a few approaches on this:

## 1 Using the get() function of the Asynctasks

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /*
    Code...
    */

    asyncPhotoBuilder = new AsyncPhotoBuilder();
    asyncPhotoBuilder.setProgressBar(progressBar);
    asyncPhotoBuilder.execute(5000);
    try{
        PuzzleList = asyncPhotoBuilder.get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*
    Code...
    */
}
```

But i think it hits the same problem with the task being finished before the request.

---

Comment: First thing... AsynTask is deprecated now. There are better alternatives

Comment: what is bette than Asyntask?

Comment: Any reason for making this "async twice"? FetchPhotoRequest.fetchPhoto is already async there is no need to wrap it in AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

As i was writing this, i did solve my problem.

I set up a flag inside the request (ready_flag) which was raised once the request has finished.

Using a runnable to check for the moment both the task was finished and also the flag was raised.

Not sure if this is the best way i could have handled this.

```
    public Runnable Start = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(asyncPhotoBuilder.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED && ready_flag){
                Init_start();
            }
            hand.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };
```

If theres a better way to do this, id love to learn.

Thanks!